# Lexus RX 300. Can't set the automatic door lock when driving

Tags: lexus, rx300

I recently purchased a used Lexus RX300 2003 or 2004 and was wondering how to enable the doors automatically locking when the transmission lever is moved out of "P" and unlock when it is moved to "P". I found the Lexus Owners manual and found how to set it, but it seems it is not getting enabled on my car.

What I did to enable it:
- Closed all the doors including the trunk.
- Turned the ignition to the ON Position
- Withing ten seconds after turning the ignition to on position, pressed and hold the driver side lock button for 5 sends

After this it says doors should automatically unlock to indicate the changes got applied, but I not seeing anything like that nor what I want is working.

Can anyone tell we what I am doing wrong? There were some other settings where to lock the doors when the car speed is 12MPH and that didn't seem to work either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you held the door lock down for five seconds, did the system respond in any way? Most vehicles with this type of setting activity will respond in some way (ie: lights will flash; doors will lock/unlock on their own; etc). If you didn't experience any type of seemingly random activity, I'd suggest you didn't hold the door lock down long enough. Just hold it down for as much time as you believe is prudent, but something like 10 seconds or so should make the difference. Worth a try.

Comment: When you did the holding of the door lock button, the Transmission was in "P" wasn't it...

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I have hold it long enough. Some people suggested looking at the blinking two dots in the clock and count. That is what I tried. Maybe I will try for 10 seconds or so this time.

Comment: @SolarMike There were two kinds of settings. One was it should be in P positiong while you do it. It is to lock the doors as soon as you shift from P to anything. And the other one should be done in any position besides P to lock the doors when the car speed is greater than 12 MPH. I tried both of them and didn't see to work.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 FYI: No I didn't notice any unusual activity in the car when I did it.